# Similar questions list is messy on the Ask a Question page

Tags: bug, asking-questions, similar-questions

I am facing below issue while creating a question for all Stack Exchange sites. Please have a look.

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: No repro on Windows, with chrome. What browser, os, etc are you using?

Comment: @10Repisn'tactiveonMSE Firefox by the look of the screenshot.

Comment: Is it the same if you [hard refresh](https://www.howtogeek.com/672607/how-to-hard-refresh-your-web-browser-to-bypass-your-cache/) the page (Ctrl + F5)?

Comment: @Ollie I don't use firefox, so I don't really know. I tried windows + firefox, and I see the bug.

Comment: I thought information is already covered in associated question so did not update the info. Yes, issue is replicatable in Firefox+Windows.